# Detecting Enter within a switch case in C?

Tags: c, switch-statement, cs50, enter

Having more trouble with this than I probably should.  I'm building a very simple bank menu interface where a user can check their balance, deposit, withdraw, or quit out of the menu.  `case 1`, `case2`, and `case3` appear to work fine, but `case 4` doesn't function properly no matter what I try off of Google.

In this current version, the `printf()` statement in `case 4` occurs, then nothing else seems to happen until I input one of the other options (1 - 3) twice, at which point the loop will cycle through and automatically use whatever the second input was.  I tried `getchar()` but that didn't seem to work (or I wasn't implementing it correctly).

Why is this behavior occurring and how can I fix it?

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

double deposit(double a, double b);
double withdraw(double a, double b);

int main(void)
{
    int resume = 1;
    int user_input = 0;
    double user_balance = 10.00;
    printf("Welcome to UBank!\n");

    while (resume)
    {
        printf("\n====================\n");
        printf("Select an operation:\n\n1. Show Balance\n2. Make a Deposit\n3. Make a Withdrawal\n4. Quit\n"
               "====================\n\n");
        scanf("%d", &user_input);

        int quit_character = 0x00;
        double deposit_amount = 0.00;
        double withdraw_amount = 0.00;

        switch (user_input)
        {
            case 1:
                printf("Balance: $%.2lf\n", user_balance);
                break;
            case 2:
                printf("How much would you like to deposit?\n");
                scanf("%lf", &deposit_amount);
                user_balance = deposit(user_balance, deposit_amount);
                break;
            case 3:
                printf("How much would you like to withdraw?\n");
                scanf("%lf", &withdraw_amount);
                user_balance = withdraw(user_balance, withdraw_amount);
                break;
            case 4:
                printf("Press Enter to finish banking or any other key to continue.\n");
                scanf("%d\n", &quit_character);
                if (quit_character == 0x0A)
                {
                    resume = 0;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}

double deposit(double a, double b)
{
    if (b > 0 && b < 10000)
    {
        return a + b;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Please enter a valid amount. (0.01 - 9999.99)\n");
        return a;
    }
}

double withdraw(double a, double b)
{
    if (b > 0 && a - b >= 10)
    {
        return a - b;
    }
    else if (b <= 0)
    {
        printf("Withdrawal amount must be greater than $0.00.\n");
    }
    else if (a - b < 10)
    {
        printf("Withdrawal amount invalid.  Remaining balance must be $10.00 or more.\n");
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: You can't use the `%d` format to read generic characters. Especially not any space character (and newline is a space character) as for the `%d` format the `scanf` function will skip (and ignore) leading space characters.

Comment: You need to learn how to check the return value of scanf to detect errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry, new to C, what would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume I want to paint the exterior of my home.  I purchase the paint, and return to my home (a 5 hour drive from the nearest store).  When I get home, I realize that I forgot to also purchase a paint brush.  I don't want to spend then next 10 hours driving to get a paint brush, but how should I apply the paint?

I could use a broom, mop, rag, my hands, my son's hands, etc., none of which are preferable to a brush.  But then I realize... I have a horse!  I clip the horse's main and make my own paintbrush!  I paint for the day, and clip my horse again next week when I need another brush.  That ends up being a lot cheaper than the 10 hour drive.

OK... that is a corny, fictional, story.  The point is that using **scanf()** for user input is like painting with a pig-nose.  It is just the wrong tool for the job.  It would be preferable to write your own user input function that works the way you expect it to.

Consider the **GetInput()** function below.  I had to make it myself, but it sure beats using **scanf()** for user input:

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  double deposit(double a, double b);
  double withdraw(double a, double b);

  /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ** Get input from user, and return it as specific types.  
  **
  ** Caller may specify NULL for any (or all) input types that are not needed.
  */
  void GetInput(int *intOut, char *charOut, double *doubleOut)
    {
    // Pointer to a temporary (allocated memory) buffer to hold user input.
    char    *line_A   = NULL;

    // Number of bytes allocated to the temporary (allocated) buffer.
    size_t   lineSize = 0;

    // Holds the number of bytes entered by the user, or (-1) for error.
    ssize_t  lineLength;

    lineLength=getline(&line_A, &lineSize, stdin);
    if(-1 == lineLength)
       {
       fprintf(stderr, "getline() failed.\n"
       goto CLEANUP;
       }

    // If the caller did not specify NULL for intOut, ...
    if(intOut)
      // Convert the string to an int and pass it back to the caller.
      *intOut = atoi(line_A); 

    if(charOut)
      *charOut = *line_A;

    if(doubleOut)
      *doubleOut = atof(line_A);

  CLEANUP:
    if(line_A)
      free(line_A);

    return;
    }

  int main(void)
  {
      int resume = 1;
      int user_input = 0;
      double user_balance = 10.00;
      printf("Welcome to UBank!\n");

      while (resume)
      {
          printf("\n====================\n");
          printf("Select an operation:\n\n1. Show Balance\n2. Make a Deposit\n3. Make a Withdrawal\n4. Quit\n"
                 "====================\n\n");
          GetInput(&user_input, NULL, NULL);     // Get an integer from the user.

          char quit_character = 0x00;
          double deposit_amount = 0.00;
          double withdraw_amount = 0.00;

          switch (user_input)
          {
              case 1:
                  printf("Balance: $%.2lf\n", user_balance);
                  break;
              case 2:
                  printf("How much would you like to deposit?\n");
                  GetInput(NULL, NULL, &deposit_amount);  // Get a double from the user.
                  user_balance = deposit(user_balance, deposit_amount);
                  break;
              case 3:
                  printf("How much would you like to withdraw?\n");
                  GetInput(NULL, NULL, &withdraw_amount);  // Get a double from the user.
                  user_balance = withdraw(user_balance, withdraw_amount);
                  break;
              case 4:
                  printf("Press Enter to finish banking or any other key to continue.\n");
                  GetInput(NULL, &quit_character, NULL);  //Get a character from the user.
                  if (quit_character == 0x0A)
                  {
                      resume = 0;
                  }
                  break;
          }
      }
  }

  double deposit(double a, double b)
  {
      if (b > 0 && b < 10000)
      {
          return a + b;
      }
      else
      {
          printf("Please enter a valid amount. (0.01 - 9999.99)\n");
          return a;
      }
  }

  double withdraw(double a, double b)
  {
      if (b > 0 && a - b >= 10)
      {
          return a - b;
      }
      else if (b <= 0)
      {
          printf("Withdrawal amount must be greater than $0.00.\n");
      }
      else if (a - b < 10)
      {
          printf("Withdrawal amount invalid.  Remaining balance must be $10.00 or more.\n");
      }
      return a;
  }
```

Comment: Unfortunately `scanf()` is what the instructor teaches, so there is some expectation to use it.  Maybe I'll skip it for that last case.  However, I want to learn: can you explain this new function to me?  Looks like your function passes in the address to the variable (depending on which case you're at).  I don't understand what's going on with the three lines at the top starting with `char *line_A` or the `getline()` function there.  Then, if the relevant pointer isn't `NULL`, it swaps the values at the address.  Why does `if(charOut)` have a `*` on both sides of the `=`, though?

Comment: How does this work with `lineSize` being initialized to 0?  Also, why do you need to `free(line_A)` if you're not using `malloc()`?

Comment: @dylosaur, **getline()** allocates memory, as needed, to hold all the chars input by the user (see man page).  **lineSize** holds the size of the memory allocated to line_A, which is 0 bytes when get line() is called here.  It works fine.  If your have further questions about get line(), feel free to post it to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @dylosaur,  I added some comments to the code about the items you had questions about.

Comment: So as I understand it, since `*line_A` is set to `NULL` and `lineSize` is set to `0`, `getline()` will allocate the buffer as needed as long as memory is available?  One more question: how come it works fine to do `atoi(line_A)` but you need the `*` for `*charOut = *line_A`?

Comment: **...as long as memory is available?** Correct.  **...but you need the * for *charOut = *line_A?** Because line_A is an array of characters, and charOut only needs a single character.  `*line_A` (the same as `line_A[0]`) takes the value of the first character (in the array of characters) and places it in (what is pointed to by) charOut.

Comment: @dylosaur, feel free to tell your instructor that I think he teaches his students to paint houses with a pig-nose!

Comment: I get it now!  Thank you for the explanation.